# How can I connect sql Server in Azure from Linux server with Php?

Tags: php, sql, azure, azure-sql-database

I have been using azure mobile services for my android application.
Then I want to access my database datas with my Localhost and Remote server using Php.

I tried the codes that is given by Azure docs below.

```
$conn = new PDO ( "sqlsrv:server = tcp:MYSERVERNAME.database.windows.net,1433; Database = MY_DATABASE_NAME", "MY_USER_NAME", "MY_PASSWORD" );
try {
    $conn->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );

} catch ( PDOException $e ) {
    print( "Error connecting to SQL Server." );
    die( print_r( $e ) );

};
```

When The code is runned on Localhost or Remote server, that is Linux server, I get error below

[image]

**EDIT**

I thought it is about Azure firewall rules and I added my IP number in Azure Firewall rules for **Server**

When I tried to connect to Server via [SQLPro](http://www.macsqlclient.com/) I could connect successfuly and I started to query. But I can not to connect via Localhost with my Php codes.

Comment: The detail about using a Macbook is irrelevant. And which Azure Firewall did you alter: SQL Database server firewall? If so, how did you set it? (127.0.0.1 won't help, as that's a localhost address). You should edit your question with that detail.

Answer (score 4):

The function you used `PDO sqlsrv:server` requires `SQLSRV extension` like `php_pdo_sqlsrv_53_nts.dll`, but which is only compatible with PHP running on Windows.

To connect to SQL server in PHP in Unix, you can use `ODBC` extension and  [Microsoft's SQL Server ODBC Driver for Linux](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=28160).

You can refer to http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-sqlsrv.php for details.

Comment: You exactly right, I solved my probled by using Azure Web App + SQL service. I use this resource https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-php-sql-database-deploy-use-git/

Answer (score 2):

Another recommendation for connecting to Azure SQL DB from your Linux server is using sqlshim. The sqlshim project aims to replicate Microsoft SQL Server Driver for PHP (sqlsrv) on Linux/OS X.

Here is a link to the project: https://github.com/radsectors/sqlshim

Here is how you would install it:

```
Download the latest release from: https://github.com/radsectors/sqlshim/releases
Extract src/sqlshim.php and src/globals.php.
Include it.
require 'src/sqlshim.php';
```

Cheers,

Meet

Answer (score -1):

Did you add the firewall exceptions to the database or the database instance?

Instance level(Run at master):

```
EXECUTE sp_set_firewall_rule N'my_rule','123.0.0.1','123.0.0.1'; 
--EXECUTE sp_set_firewall_rule N'rule_name','IP_Range_low','IP_Range_high';
```

Database Level (Run at target DB):

```
EXECUTE sp_set_database_firewall_rule N'my_db_rule'; 
,'123.0.0.1'  --IP_Range_low
,'123.0.0.1'  --IP_Range_high
```